# CuteFTP not transfering files in certain folders

Tags: ftp

I have such big folder **myfolder1** (has 2500 files inside and 55 subfolders).
**Myfolder1**, has one folder named **myfolder2** and it has 1900 files.

So I want to download all files and subfolders in **myfolder1** except all the files that exists in **myfolder2**. Is it possible to write a filter or something and not to transfer that folder.

Comment: what version of CuteFTP are you using? You can probably use scripts and/or a macro. OTherwise why not restructure and move that one folder outside the other?

Comment: I use cuteftp 8.3 pro. I don't restructure because "myfolder2" includes temporary files and I don't want to delete them from remote folder.

Comment: you do not have to delete/reupload any files to move them

Answer (score 0):

[Choosing which files and folders to display (CuteFP Filtering)](http://help.globalscape.com/help/cuteftp7/choosing_which_files_and_folders_to_display.htm)

**To choose which folders to display**

1. From the menu, select View > Filter.
2. Select Enable Filtering.
3. Select Apply filtering to folder name(s).
4. Select the Filter Mask tab.
5. Enter the names of files and folders you want to display, or use
   wildcard masks to include groups of files and folders.
6. Select Add.
7. Select the Filter NOT Mask tab.
8. Enter the names of files and folders you want to Hide, or use
   wildcard masks  to exclude groups of files and folders.
9. Select OK.

**To use filters with transfers**

1. From the menu, select View > Filter.
2. Select Enable Filtering.
3. Select Apply to file transfers.
4. Set your filters in the Filter Mask tab and Filter NOT Mask tab.
5. Select OK.